# Joining two select queries and ordering results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Basically I'm just unsure as to why this query is failing to execute:

```
(SELECT replies.reply_post, replies.reply_content, replies.reply_date AS d, members.username
     FROM (replies) AS a 
        INNER JOIN members ON replies.reply_by = members.id)

            UNION

(SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_title, posts.post_date AS d, members.username 
     FROM (posts) as b 
        WHERE posts.post_set = 0 
           INNER JOIN members ON posts.post_by = members.id)

ORDER BY d DESC LIMIT 5
```

I'm getting this error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'a INNER JOIN members ON replies.re' at line 2

All I'm trying to do is select the 5 most recent rows (dates) from these two tables. I've tried Join, union etc and I've seen numerous queries where people have put another query after the FROM statement and that just makes no logical sense to me as to how that works?

Am I safe to say that you can join the same table from two different but joined queries? Or am I taking completely the wrong approach, because frankly I can't seem see how this query is failing despite reading the error message.

(The two queries on there own work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is syntax error in your query at below part :

```
FROM (posts) as b 
        WHERE posts.post_set = 0 
           INNER JOIN members ON posts.post_by = members.id)
```

Inner join should come first before where condition. Also your join conditions are wrong. You need to apply conditions like

```
INNER JOIN members ON a.reply_by = members.id)
INNER JOIN members ON b.post_by = members.id)
```

So your query should be like this

```
(SELECT a.reply_post, a.reply_content, a.reply_date AS d, members.username
 FROM (replies) AS a 
 INNER JOIN members ON a.reply_by = members.id)

 UNION

(SELECT b.post_id, b.post_title, b.post_date AS d, members.username 
 FROM (posts) as b 
 INNER JOIN members ON b.post_by = members.id
 WHERE b.post_set = 0)

ORDER BY d DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Oh wow somethings just cross my mind, thank you very much. Though why is that I must use b.post_set (and others) rather than posts.post_set?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(SELECT a.reply_post, a.reply_content, a.reply_date AS d, members.username
 FROM replies AS a 
    INNER JOIN members ON a.reply_by = members.id)

        UNION

(SELECT b.post_id, b.post_title, b.post_date AS d, members.username 
 FROM posts as b 
    INNER JOIN members ON b.post_by = members.id 
    WHERE b.post_set = 0)  /* Use where condition after matching Id's using ON */

ORDER BY d DESC LIMIT 5
```